# bug in the facebook developer website

Tags: facebook, x-facebook-platform

The facebook developer website won't remember the Site URL for my app. I tried deleting the APP and recreating the app. In the new app I recreated I set the Site URL at the Web section but when I look again in the Basic section of the app I don't see the Site URL modified. It's still empty. I tried this several times to set the Site URL at the Web Section but it's still empty when I revisit the page. So what is going on? So I try to set the Site URL but why doesn't it let me???

Is this a bug in the facebook platform? I would expect more out of a site like facebook.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know this might sound insulting but did you hit save at the bottom of the screen after you edited it? Im saying because i did this a couple times until i found the save/submit button on the bottom.

Comment: Yes I did hit the Save button. It doesn't remember the website.

Comment: okay, sorry, just checking, happened to me before :)

Comment: It works if I set the Site URL to say http://www.microsoft.com. But I have a free hosting subdomain: http://verdanax.comule.com and It doesn't work. I tried to set the domain to comule.com but it says comule.com is not a valid domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comule.com is blacklisted as a known spammy site. Facebook won't scrape any site that shows up in a [URIBL](https://admin.uribl.com/)

You need to find a different web host.

Facebook offers free hosting through Heroku. You can sign up from an [app setup page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I sign up for paid hosting with the guys from comule.com and I will have a normal domain "mydomain.com" it will be ok? I assume it won't know where I am hosting it and it's not free so I assume it'll be ok.

Comment: Don't assume anything. Comule is blacklisted. I'd assume their whole block of IP addresses are also blacklisted. There are plenty of other hotsts out there who aren't blacklisted. I'd use one of them rather than stick with a spammers haven.